# Can't empty a bash array (bash --version 3.2.25)

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

My bash array never empty itself.

I am using bash 3.2.25.
I tried using the folowing methods:

```
declare -a array

# fill array...

# 1
array=()

# 2
empty_array=()
array=( "${empty_array[@]}" )

# 3
unset array
```

My array never get emptied, am I doing something wrong?

Full code as requested :

```
declare -a array

function get_array() {

#active_tills=()

#unset active_tills

#active_tills=( "${active_tills[@]}" )

# fill array
    while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        line=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1)
        if [ -n "$line" ] ; then
            to_add+="$line "
        fi
    done < "$request_tmp"
    array=($(echo $to_add))
    return 0
}
```

Then

```
get_array
for host in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "=> $host"
done
# 1
# 2
# 3

get_array
for host in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "=> $host"
done
# 1
# 2
# 3 
# 1
# 2 
# 3
```

Comment: Did you really type `array=(( "${empty_array[@]}" )`? It should give you an error.

Comment: Using `array=()` works for me; I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I assume those are the three methods you've attempted to use to empty your array, and the missing brace was a pasting error. ```unset array``` should work, can we see a more complete example?

Comment: Well my code is as simple as that :/ I don't get why my array just don't empty. Also yes the ( was a typo

Comment: How are you trying to confirm that your array is empty?

Comment: I am trying to empty it, my function empty a global array then fill it, so that each call have a fresh filled array. But at second call the array isnt emptied, the new elements just append after the past ones

Comment: Show an *exact* example that demonstrates the array is not empty, that we can run and see for ourselves. I suspect you are calling your function in a subshell.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are using a 9-year-old release of `bash`?

Comment: Yes, it's a production environment that I have to deal with haha. I am starting thinking this is a serious bug, I mean even when I asked at first I thought about It. But this makes no sense.

Comment: Your production environment is missing 30+ patches released over a 7-year period; you should bug someone about upgrading to 3.2.57 at the very least.

Comment: We already have better environments, it just depend on which client use what and what we are still supporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_add` is also a global variable, and you don't reset its value before appending to it. However, you don't need it: you can append directly to the array.

```
declare -a array

function get_array() {

  local line rest

  array=()
  while read -r line rest || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [ -n "$line" ] ; then
      array+=("$line")
    fi
  done < "$request_tmp"
  return 0
}
```

As an aside, if you can guarantee that the input file ends with a newline (as is required of a proper text file in POSIX), you don't need the `|| [[ -n $line ]]` hack in your `while` loop.

Comment: to_add is defined nowhere, I mean it's used directly here. Does it make it global? that would explain everything. Also at first I was willing to use array+=("$line") but I was using array+="$line"... Thanks

Comment: Any variable set in a function is global by default. You don't need to define variables, per se; they come into existence the moment you assign a value to a name. You can make a variable local with the `local` command; I'll update the question to demonstrate that.